# MUI - Helper text for a Select using TextField is displaying below the input instead of with in input field

Tags: material-ui

This is how it appears.

[image]

This is the rendering code -

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
  <Grid item xs={space} key={1}>
    <TextField
      value={""}
      onChange={(e) => {}}
      select // tell TextField to render select
      label="Status"
      fullWidth
      helperText="123"
    ></TextField>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Did you try using `placeholder="" ` attribute ?

Comment: Tried placeholder as well. It doesn't show anything with this attribute.

Answer (score 1):

`helperText` is supposed to work like that.

According to the [API Doc](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/select/) for the `Select` component, there is no such option as `placeholder`, which means you cannot use it even if you use it inside the `TextField` component by passing the `select` prop.

However, you can customize it by using props called `renderValue` from the `Select` component, which will help you achieve what you wanted.

Something like this:

```
  const menuItems = [
    {
      value: "active",
      label: "Active",
    },
    {
      value: "inactive",
      label: "Inactive",
    },
    {
      value: "pending",
      label: "Pending",
    },
  ];

 <TextField
          onChange={(e) => {}}
          select
          label="Status"
          fullWidth
          helperText="123"
          defaultValue=""
          InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
          SelectProps={{
            displayEmpty: true,
            renderValue: (selected) => {
              if (!selected) {
                return <em>Placeholder</em>;
              }
              return menuItems.find((x) => x.value === selected).label;
            },
          }}
          render
        >
          {menuItems.map((option) => (
            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </TextField>
```

For a better experience, I recommend using the `Autocomplete` component, which allows you to easily implement placeholders and also has many options such as search.

[Autocomplete component](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/)

Hope it helps :)